# Definite Normal Integrals, need analytical solution

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Can any one suggest me a direction to attack following integral? I need an analytical solution for that.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \left[ \frac{\{\phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2}})\}^2}{\Phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2}}) \Phi(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2}})}     \right] dx
\end{equation}

where $\phi(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\alpha^2/2}$ is Standard Gaussian probability distribution function and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \phi(\alpha)d\alpha$ ~is standard Gaussian Cumulative distribution function,

Comment: Does $\phi^2(x)$ mean $[\phi(x)]^2$ or $\phi(\phi(x))$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the special case $b=0$, the answer is
$$ \frac{2 e^{-1/a^2}}{\pi \left(1 - \text{erf}(1/(\sqrt{2}a))^2\right)}$$
In general, it seems unlikely that there should be a closed form, though stranger things have happened.  Do you have any reason to think there is one?

Comment: Thank you Robert, I have No Idea whether it has closed form or not, however closed-form will help me.